# Rijndael alternative for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, encryption, openssl, rijndael

I have a project in c#, Windows that uses Rijndael object.

I'm suppoesd to write it in c++,Linux.

I understood that I'm supposed to use openssl/aes, but couldn't figure out how.

What are the includes? what is the class name? the methods?

what should I use instead of: Rijndael.create(), Rijndael.KeySize(),Rijndael.IV(), etc.

Thanks in Advance.

Sara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example source code is available [here](http://saju.net.in/blog/?p=36). Make sure you link with `-lcrypto`.

EDIT the link currently does not work; I copy the source from [an archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20140802152721/http://saju.net.in/blog/?p=36):

```
/**
  AES encryption/decryption demo program using OpenSSL EVP apis
  gcc -Wall openssl_aes.c -lcrypto

  this is public domain code. 

  Saju Pillai (saju.pillai@gmail.com)
**/

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

/**
 * Create an 256 bit key and IV using the supplied key_data. salt can be added for taste.
 * Fills in the encryption and decryption ctx objects and returns 0 on success
 **/
int aes_init(unsigned char *key_data, int key_data_len, unsigned char *salt, EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e_ctx, 
         EVP_CIPHER_CTX *d_ctx)
{
  int i, nrounds = 5;
  unsigned char key[32], iv[32];

  /*
   * Gen key & IV for AES 256 CBC mode. A SHA1 digest is used to hash the supplied key material.
   * nrounds is the number of times the we hash the material. More rounds are more secure but
   * slower.
   */
  i = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), salt, key_data, key_data_len, nrounds, key, iv);
  if (i != 32) {
    printf("Key size is %d bits - should be 256 bits\n", i);
    return -1;
  }

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(e_ctx);
  EVP_EncryptInit_ex(e_ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(d_ctx);
  EVP_DecryptInit_ex(d_ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);

  return 0;
}

/*
 * Encrypt *len bytes of data
 * All data going in & out is considered binary (unsigned char[])
 */
unsigned char *aes_encrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e, unsigned char *plaintext, int *len)
{
  /* max ciphertext len for a n bytes of plaintext is n + AES_BLOCK_SIZE -1 bytes */
  int c_len = *len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE, f_len = 0;
  unsigned char *ciphertext = malloc(c_len);

  /* allows reusing of 'e' for multiple encryption cycles */
  EVP_EncryptInit_ex(e, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  /* update ciphertext, c_len is filled with the length of ciphertext generated,
    *len is the size of plaintext in bytes */
  EVP_EncryptUpdate(e, ciphertext, &c_len, plaintext, *len);

  /* update ciphertext with the final remaining bytes */
  EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(e, ciphertext+c_len, &f_len);

  *len = c_len + f_len;
  return ciphertext;
}

/*
 * Decrypt *len bytes of ciphertext
 */
unsigned char *aes_decrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e, unsigned char *ciphertext, int *len)
{
  /* because we have padding ON, we must allocate an extra cipher block size of memory */
  int p_len = *len, f_len = 0;
  unsigned char *plaintext = malloc(p_len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

  EVP_DecryptInit_ex(e, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  EVP_DecryptUpdate(e, plaintext, &p_len, ciphertext, *len);
  EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(e, plaintext+p_len, &f_len);

  *len = p_len + f_len;
  return plaintext;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /* "opaque" encryption, decryption ctx structures that libcrypto uses to record
     status of enc/dec operations */
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX en, de;

  /* 8 bytes to salt the key_data during key generation. This is an example of
     compiled in salt. We just read the bit pattern created by these two 4 byte 
     integers on the stack as 64 bits of contigous salt material - 
     ofcourse this only works if sizeof(int) >= 4 */
  unsigned int salt[] = {12345, 54321};
  unsigned char *key_data;
  int key_data_len, i;
  char *input[] = {"a", "abcd", "this is a test", "this is a bigger test", 
               "\nWho are you ?\nI am the 'Doctor'.\n'Doctor' who ?\nPrecisely!",
               NULL};

  /* the key_data is read from the argument list */
  key_data = (unsigned char *)argv[1];
  key_data_len = strlen(argv[1]);

  /* gen key and iv. init the cipher ctx object */
  if (aes_init(key_data, key_data_len, (unsigned char *)&salt, &en, &de)) {
    printf("Couldn't initialize AES cipher\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* encrypt and decrypt each input string and compare with the original */
  for (i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
    char *plaintext;
    unsigned char *ciphertext;
    int olen, len;

    /* The enc/dec functions deal with binary data and not C strings. strlen() will 
       return length of the string without counting the '\0' string marker. We always
       pass in the marker byte to the encrypt/decrypt functions so that after decryption 
       we end up with a legal C string */
    olen = len = strlen(input[i])+1;

    ciphertext = aes_encrypt(&en, (unsigned char *)input[i], &len);
    plaintext = (char *)aes_decrypt(&de, ciphertext, &len);

    if (strncmp(plaintext, input[i], olen)) 
      printf("FAIL: enc/dec failed for \"%s\"\n", input[i]);
    else 
      printf("OK: enc/dec ok for \"%s\"\n", plaintext);

    free(ciphertext);
    free(plaintext);
  }

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&en);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&de);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

have a look at [cryptopp](http://www.cryptopp.com/). They have Rijndael (AES) "raw" and in block modes (CBC etc.). Look at their wiki documentation, they have many code samples.

It is a popular crypto library, they have also a Windows version, so you can use on both platforms. If you wish to keep your current implementation on Windows, you may want to have your custom wrapper, so that you can choose an underlying implementation on each platform.

**EDIT**: a sample from my code

```
using namespace CryptoPP;

CBC_Mode< CryptoPP::AES >::Encryption encryptor;

std::string clearText("hello world");
std::string encrypted;

StringSource( clearText, true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter( encryptor,
        new StringSink( encrypted )
    )
);
```