# AES with padding pkcs7 c++ code

Tags: c++, crypto++, pkcs#7

I need an example of string encryption (in C++ -> I'm working on linux-Ubuntu) with aes-cbc256 and a padding: PKCS7
Please help.

---

For the following code how can I set the IV to 0 and set the key value to a string value? I would also like to add the pkcs7 padding. I'm using the crypto++ lib (in Linux)

```
// Driver.cpp   
//      

#include "stdafx.h"    
#include "cryptopp/dll.h"    
#include "cryptopp/default.h"    
#include "crypto++/osrng.h"    
using CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool;    

#include <iostream>    
using std::cout;    
using std::cerr;       

#include <string>    
using std::string;       

#include "crypto++/cryptlib.h"    
using CryptoPP::Exception;        

#include "crypto++/hex.h"    
using CryptoPP::HexEncoder;    
using CryptoPP::HexDecoder;        

#include "crypto++/filters.h"    
using CryptoPP::StringSink;    
using CryptoPP::StringSource;    
using CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter;        

#include "crypto++/aes.h"    
using CryptoPP::AES;       

#include "crypto++/ccm.h"    
using CryptoPP::CBC_Mode;       

#include "assert.h"        

int main(int argc, char* argv[])    
{    
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;        

    byte key[ AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ];    
    prng.GenerateBlock( key, sizeof(key) );        

    byte iv[ AES::BLOCKSIZE];    
    iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE] = 0;    
    //prng.GenerateBlock(iv,  sizeof(iv) );        

    string plain = "CBC Mode Test";    
    string cipher, encoded, recovered;       

    // Pretty print key    
    encoded.clear();    
    StringSource( key, sizeof(key), true,    
                  new HexEncoder(new StringSink( encoded )) // HexEncoder    
    ); // StringSource

    cout << "key: " << encoded << endl;        

    // Pretty print iv    
    encoded.clear();

    StringSource( iv, sizeof(iv), true,    
        new HexEncoder(new StringSink( encoded )) // HexEncoder    
    ); // StringSource

    cout << "iv: " << encoded << endl;       

    /*********************************\
    \*********************************/

    try    
    {    
        cout << "plain text: " << plain << endl;            
        CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;    
        e.SetKeyWithIV( key, sizeof(key), iv );     

        // The StreamTransformationFilter adds padding    
        //  as required. ECB and CBC Mode must be padded    
        //  to the block size of the cipher.    
        StringSource( plain, true,     
            new StreamTransformationFilter( e,    
                new StringSink( cipher )    
            ) // StreamTransformationFilter          
        ); // StringSource    
    }    
    catch( CryptoPP::Exception& e )    
    {    
        cerr << "Caught Exception..." << endl;    
        cerr << e.what() << endl;    
        cerr << endl;    
    }    

    /*********************************\    
    \*********************************/    

    // Pretty print    
    encoded.clear();    
    StringSource( cipher, true,    
        new HexEncoder(    
            new StringSink( encoded )    
        ) // HexEncoder    
    ); // StringSource    
    cout << "cipher text: " << encoded << endl;    

    /*********************************\    
    \*********************************/    

    try    
    {    
        CBC_Mode< AES >::Decryption d;    
        d.SetKeyWithIV( key, sizeof(key), iv );    

        // The StreamTransformationFilter removes    
        //  padding as required.    
        StringSource s( cipher, true,     
            new StreamTransformationFilter( d,    
                new StringSink( recovered )    
            ) // StreamTransformationFilter    
        ); // StringSource    

        cout << "recovered text: " << recovered << endl;    
    }    
    catch( CryptoPP::Exception& e )    
    {    
        cerr << "Caught Exception..." << endl;    
        cerr << e.what() << endl;    
        cerr << endl;    
    }    

    /*********************************\    
    \*********************************/    

    assert( plain == recovered );    

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: ok. `byte` is an `unsigned char`. `AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH` is usually 16. So you have an array of length 16 of unsigned chars. Just copy your string to it converting `char` to `unsigned char`, and **padding** the rest of the `key` array with a known value, e.g. 0. That's re: the key

Comment: as for iv, do you mean "all 0's"? if so, just fill it with 0's, or any other value that you like.

Comment: So the aes is 128. Do you mean i have to change the  prng.GenerateBlock( key, sizeof(key) ); with key[aes::default_keylenght]='hello0000000000'?..if no can you PLEASE write the correct code? I would really appreciate it:). What about the padding? It is PKCS7? Where can i change or see the value?..THX A LOT!

Comment: And one more question. How can i print the key value? cout<<"key: "<<key<<endl; prints a total different value for key:(

Answer (score 10):

OpenSSL uses PKCS7 padding by default.  This padding means when your data is not a multiple of the block size, you pad *n* bytes of the value *n*, where *n* is however many bytes you need to get to the block size.  AES's block size is 16.

Here's an example on how to encrypt a string using AES256-cbc with OpenSSL.  The OpenSSL documentation also has [examples](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html), although they use different ciphers.  This example does no error checking.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

#include <openssl/evp.h>

int main()
{
    // ctx holds the state of the encryption algorithm so that it doesn't
    // reset back to its initial state while encrypting more than 1 block.
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);

    unsigned char key[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
                   0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
                   0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
                   0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f};
    unsigned char iv[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    assert(sizeof(key) == 32);  // AES256 key size
    assert(sizeof(iv) == 16);   // IV is always the AES block size

    // If data isn't a multiple of 16, the default behavior is to pad with
    // n bytes of value n, where n is the number of padding bytes required
    // to make data a multiple of the block size.  This is PKCS7 padding.
    // The output then will be a multiple of the block size.
    std::string plain("encrypt me");
    std::vector<unsigned char> encrypted;
    size_t max_output_len = plain.length() + 16 - (plain.length() % 16);
    encrypted.resize(max_output_len);

    // Enc is 1 to encrypt, 0 to decrypt, or -1 (see documentation).
    EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv, 1);

    // EVP_CipherUpdate can encrypt all your data at once, or you can do
    // small chunks at a time.
    int actual_size = 0;
    EVP_CipherUpdate(&ctx,
             &encrypted[0], &actual_size,
             reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&plain[0]), plain.size());

    // EVP_CipherFinal_ex is what applies the padding.  If your data is
    // a multiple of the block size, you'll get an extra AES block filled
    // with nothing but padding.
    int final_size;
    EVP_CipherFinal_ex(&ctx, &encrypted[actual_size], &final_size);
    actual_size += final_size;

    encrypted.resize(actual_size);

    for( size_t index = 0; index < encrypted.size(); ++index )
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') <<
            static_cast<unsigned int>(encrypted[index]);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

Name it `encrypt.cpp` and compile with:

```
g++ encrypt.cpp -o encrypt -lcrypto -lssl -Wall
```

You'll get this output:

```
338d2a9e28208cad84c457eb9bd91c81
```

You can verify correctness by running the OpenSSL command-line utility from the command prompt:

```
$ echo -n "encrypt me" > to_encrypt
$ openssl enc -in to_encrypt -out encrypted -e -aes-256-cbc \
-K 000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f \
-iv 00000000000000000000000000000000
$ hexdump -C encrypted
```

And the hexdump will show the same bytes as the c++ program.

```
00000000  33 8d 2a 9e 28 20 8c ad  84 c4 57 eb 9b d9 1c 81  |3.*.( ....W.....|
```

Comment: How can I decrypt the encoded string? Also i have to add base64 after encription. How can i use openssl for the second option: base64? Thx:)....! Sorry for asking studpid question but for me it's all new in this area:)...ANd examples are so few:(. Thx again!!:)

Comment: The code is the same. I just have to change the line: EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv, 1); with 0 not 1,no?

Comment: In my code the key is a password called for example hello. I have the following error: int main(): Assertion `sizeof(key) == 32' failed.
Aborted

Comment: @she:  Yeah, I think you just have to change the 1 to a 0 in `EVP_CipherInit_ex` to decrypt.  As for the assert, an AES256 key is 32 bytes.  It has to be 32 bytes in this `EVP_Cipher_*` API.  There is an OpenSSL API where it can take a password and generate an AES256 key, but I'm not sure off hand what it is.  I know there is such an API because you can do that using the command line utility like this:  `openssl aes-256-cbc -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -e -in plain_text_file -out encrypted_file` and then it asks for a password.  Perhaps post another question asking how to do it.

Comment: ...If you have time please send me a link from where i can download the crypto++ lib in order to work properly. Thx.

Comment: @she:  This example uses OpenSSL, not crypto++.  You can download the OpenSSL source code here:  http://www.openssl.org/source/, or install it from your Linux package manager, or get a binary version if you're on Windows here:  http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: I know..I did install OpenSSL too. The thing is that my key code is a string. THe code is not working properly if i change the hexa vakues from the key in a string value

Comment: Do you have the decryption code?:) Can you please put here the decryption for the encryption example? I would appreciate:). THX

Comment: Don't you mean size_t max_output_len  = plain.length() + 16 - (plain.length() % 16);

Comment: @velcrow:  Yes, thanks!  Luckily my buggy code was over-allocating the space instead of under-allocating it.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

look also at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508646/rijndael-alternative-for-linux)

I suggest checking out [cryptopp](http://www.cryptopp.com). Here's a code sample:

```
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption encryptor;
byte* key;
size_t keylen;
// ... acquire key

encryptor.SetKey( key, keylen );

std::string input;
std::string result;
// read input ...

StringSource( input, true,
       new StreamTransformationFilter( encryptor, new StringSink( result ),
     StreamTransformationFilter::PKCS_PADDING));
```

The values for padding mode in `StreamTransformationFilter` can be:

```
BlockPaddingScheme { 
  NO_PADDING, ZEROS_PADDING, PKCS_PADDING, ONE_AND_ZEROS_PADDING, 
  DEFAULT_PADDING 
}
```

EDIT: replaced the padding mode in the sample to pkcs

Comment: THX A LOT. I would appreciate if you could give me a link where a c++ code that encodes a string with aes,cbc and pkcs padding is given as example:d. Thx...:D

Comment: I can't open cryptoop page:(.... I did search a lot on the internet...but i really didn't find a simple example where the pkcs7 padding is also included when the string is crypted with aes.

Comment: @she: weird - it opens ok for me... Actually, the sample I gave here seems to do what you need - I edited it a bit to change the padding value and added setting a key. Anyway, here's a sample at cryptopp wiki: http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CBC, you just need to add padding parameter which is optional and is omitted in their examples.

Comment: thx a lot:)...the ex you gave is on windows platform. I'm working on linux:ubuntu 9.10....i can't test the code

Comment: @she: no, it's just their attached code samples include the MSVC project files. I work on Linux myself - I just throw them (the .dsp) away, the code compiles and runs perfectly on Linux (CentOS)

Comment: unfortunally i do have an error when i type the command make install - for the crypto++ lib. I'm going to try to work with openssl. Than a lot anway:). In open ssl i did find the command: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(). I'm going to...try to read..and work with it. Have great hollidays!!

Comment: did you use openssl? I did test one example that i found on the internet..but it's not working properly. If you have a code that works correctly please send me the link..thx

Comment: I did try to run the sample 1 example from here: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=21877. When writting g++ sample1.cpp -o sample1 -lcrypto ..it pops up a lot of errors like:  undefined reference to `CryptoPP::BlockTransformation::AdvancedProcessBlocks(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const'
/tmp/ccHGNwCg.o:( .rodata. _ZTVN8CryptoPP13AlgorithmImplINS_25SimpleKeyingInterfaceImplINS_8TwoBasesINS_11BlockCipherENS_13Rijndael_InfoEEES5_EES6_EE[ vtab;e...

Comment: @she: have you succeeded with installing the cryptopp BTW? I think that your compiler can't find the cryptopp include files. You need either to add it to the command options, e.g. `g++ --I/usr/include/cryptopp ...`, or change the #include directive in the code to `#include <cryptopp/aes.h>` etc. (assuming it is installed under `/usr/include`). Also, I think that the `-l` option should be `-lcryptopp`. And verify that the libcryptopp.so sits in your compiler's  default library search path, or you'll need to direct it there by the `-L` option. And nice link BTW. good luck!

Comment: @she: `-I` (one minus), sorry

Comment: Hi again. No I didn't. I still have errors. I'll try to install the library again. Maybe I'm missing something at installation. Maybe..i don't do somethig right..Hmm..THX A LOT1

Comment: AT command make install I have the following error: cp: cannot stat `*.so': No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1

Comment: @she: do you follow the installation instruction? seems that the library (the .so file ) is not created. You may also check the software repository for your system for a version of cryptopp that's been tested and packaged for your distribution. I've read that Ubuntu has a special installation procedure. E.g. on my system we use the `yum` utility. And BTW, how do you expect the example to compile if you don't have the cryptopp library yet? :)

Comment: I did install the libcrypto library from this page: http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-10.10/ubuntu-main-i386/libgcrypt11_1.4.5-2ubuntu1_i386.deb.html

Comment: i have the following error when compiling g++ test.cpp -o tess -lcrypto++

Comment: /tmp/cc7yhd6w.o: In function `CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char,  true>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE8allocateEjPKv[CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, true>::allocate(unsigned int, void const*)]+0x2b): undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AlignedAllocate(unsigned int)'
test.cpp:( .text._ZN8CryptoPP20AllocatorWithCleanupIhLb1EE8allocateEjPKv[CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, true>::allocate(unsigned /...

Comment: hmm... no idea. There is a forum for cryptopp users at http://groups.google.com/group/cryptopp-users, perhaps you can ask there.

Comment: I FINALLY SUCCEED TO INSTALL LIBCRYPTO++. I hadn't the correct package, that's why i had errors. In the end with the package libcrypto++5.6 it compiles without errors:D I am so happy:). Thx davka for everything:)

Comment: I am going to write a simple encryption code with aes 128, cbc, pkcs7, and key="hello". If something will go wrong i will ask for your help. I am in hurry...and i did spend a lot of time with installing libraries in ubuntu:)...it's the ugliest thing...

Comment: no problem. you can write to me directly if you prefer - davidk at navajosystems dotcom. BTW, the key should be of a specific size, as defined by CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, usually 16 bytes. So you can't use "hello", or at least you need to pad it to the right size.

Comment: Devka about the pointer key..how can I initialize it with the "hello" string value?

Comment: you better define it as in your answer - `byte key[ AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ];`. Than you can just copy anything you want to it, up to the length. Don't forget to initialize it, so you don't have garbage in the rest of it

Comment: I did put byte key[ AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ] ="hello";
and then used : encryptor.SetKey( key,sizeof(key));

std::string input;
std::string result;
// read input ...
input="test";
StringSource( input, true,
       new StreamTransformationFilter( encryptor, new StringSink( result ),
     StreamTransformationFilter::PKCS_PADDING));
 I have the following error : aes/cbc: 3218054424 is not a valid key. Any ideeas? THX.

Comment: well, I don't know what are the rules/restrictions for AES key, but haven't I warned you about clearing the array first? :) Anyway, why is this important for you to use "hello" as key? Just to get it up and running, fill the key with some numbers, e.g. `for (int i=0; i < AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH; ++i) key[i]=(byte)i;` or anything.

Comment: In my case there is an encryption KEY I need to use. The encryption key is something like this:"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX". The iv is set to 0, and the padding is 7. I searched a lot of an example where the aes encryption is resolved using a string key. I didn't find anything:(...i don't know how to do it. Have any ideeas?

Comment: you can perhaps use hash function on the "key" string, e.g. MD5 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) or SHA-1 and use their output as a key to AES. Both are supported by the cryptopp. MD5 seems to suit you better as its output is 128 bits long, exactly as the key size you need, I think. Pay attention to the input size  though - I don't know if there is a requirement for **minimal** input size for md5. If there is, you may need to pad your string.

Comment: BTW, have you considered accepting the answer? It indeed seems that this is path you're taking... ;)

Comment: My key is a specific passwd. Thx for advice!..i'm looking to some examples..hope i find some..with my requirements.

Comment: It's not that easy...because ..my aes encrypted message has to be compatible with a .net webservice:D.( on Windows). As I know

Comment: so it's something like..encryption on linux..c++ and decription on windows .net