# open source code for RSA implementation in C/C++ (Use library or write my own)

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I need open source code for RSA implementation (encrypt/decrypt and others). Can anyone suggest some.

Edit:
Is it good to use a open source library like opessl or write it your own (Library include other redundant stuff too)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenSSL library is the obvious choice. [CryptLib](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/) is another option, yet you need to check the license (it's quite specific).

Regarding writing your own code: 
if you need *only* RSA, it's not large and you can write it yourself. However, RSA is almost never used by its own. Usually encryption is performed using random key and symmetric algorithm, and then the random key is encrypted with RSA. So if you want data encryption and decide to write your own stuff, you will be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: And secure use of RSA usually requires correct padding. And you probably don't want to do that on your own.

Comment: Writing a modular exponentiation is a good programming exercise. But a proper, secure RSA implementation must also mind many subtle details such as masking to counteract timing attacks, and that is tricky. So, _please_, do not write your own RSA code. Use a library.

Comment: You should **not** write your own implementation of RSA!  There are many side-channel attacks on RSA implementations that can be used to recover private keys.  Use a well-tested implementation rather than your own to ensure that, to the maximum extent possible, you do not accidentally leak the private key!

Comment: @templatetypedef I can't agree more about using a well tested library.  There is _one_ particular implementation on [Google code](https://code.google.com/p/rsa-in-c/) that doesn't look half bad. But I'd much rather use a tested implementation from a reputable source.

Answer (score 4):

[Crypto++ Library is a free C++ class library of cryptographic schemes.](http://www.cryptopp.com/) Amongst the many different encryption systems it supplies it also provides RSA.

In general, it is never a good idea to roll your own encryption/security code, unless this is what you are good at. Secure code is HARD, and even in established libraries loopholes, bugs and faults pop up every once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL would be the standard choice. http://www.openssl.org/
http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rsa.html describes its API.

Answer (score 1):

have a look also at [cryptopp](http://www.cryptopp.com/). I use it and it is very convenient (haven't use the RSA though).

see my other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508646/rijndael-alternative-for-linux) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508749/aes-with-padding-pkcs7-c-code/4509430#4509430).